# Cast Object array to Custom Class array

Tags: java, arrays, object

i created a class derived of Object and I have a object array.
how to do cast **object array** to **my class array**?

```
public class CastArray{

public CastArray(){
}

public long toLong(){
    return Long.parseLong(this.toString());
}    

public double toDouble(){
    return Double.parseDouble(this.toString());
}

public int toInteger(){
    return Integer.parseInt(this.toString());
}
}<br />
```

return Error:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LBasic.CastArray;

Comment: In java you don't need to explicitly write "extends Object".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit vague but let me make an attempt to answer it. if the object array is actually an array of your class, you can do a direct cast to your array e.g. `A[] a = (A[]) objArray;`. Alternatively, if you know that each element can be cast into your class (is an instance of your class or one of its sub classes), you can clone it by creating a new array and adding each element with a cast to your class. e.g.:

```
A[] a = new A[objArray.length];
int i = 0;
for (Object o : objArray) {
   a[i++] = (A) o;
}
```

Comment: this is how it's done `System.arrayCopy(objArray, 0, a, 0, a.length)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking how to do this:

Object[] objectArray = {};

CastArray castArray = (CastArray)objectArray;

If this is the case you can't.

Comment: Well one could do something like this: Badge[] badges = (Badge[]) clazz.cast(Array.newInstance(clazz.getComponentType(), 0));

Answer (score 1):

The [Arrays.copyOf(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29) could be a solution for you.

Best regards!